# function array_push returns empty array

Tags: php

I try to save the rows of a table in an array but I am getting an empty array. 
My code is:

```
$a = array();
$b = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $b["id"] = $row["id"];
        $b["title"] = $row["title"];
        $b["description"] = $row["description"];
        $b["lat"] = $row["lat"];
        $b["lng"] = $row["lng"];
        $b["walkId"] = $row["walkId"];
        echo json_encode($b);
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
    echo json_encode($a);
}
```

Using `echo json_encode($b);` I see the results one by one but the array a is empty.

EDIT 1

After Random's help, using the `echo print_r($a,true);` I am getting the below screenshot: [image: error]

And the screenshot from other tables in which I get the data correctly is:
[image: correct]

EDIT 2

problem with json_encode. I get the below
[{"id":"55","title":"\u00ce\u203a\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u2026\u00ce\u00bb\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u2026\u00ce\u00b4\u00ce\u00ac\u00ce\u00b4\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ba\u00ce\u00b1","description":"\u00ce\u201c\u00ce\u00b5\u00ce\u00bd\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ba\u00ce\u00ae \u00ce\u00b1\u00ce\u00bd\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u2020\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00ac \u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b1 x\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00b1\u00ce\u00ba\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b7\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00b9\u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ba\u00ce\u00ac \u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b7\u00cf\u201a \u00ce\u00b3\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00bf\u00ce\u00bd\u00ce\u00bf\u00ce\u00bc\u00ce\u00af\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u201a \u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b7\u00cf","lat":"40.634356","lng":"22.940716","walkId":"92"},{"id":"56","title":"\u00ce\u2018\u00ce\u00b3\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00ac \u00ce\u0153\u00ce\u00bf\u00ce\u00b4\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ac\u00ce\u00bd\u00ce\u00bf","description":"H \u00ce\u00b9\u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00af\u00ce\u00b1 \u00ce\u00bc\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u201a \u00ce\u00b9\u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ba\u00ce\u00ae\u00cf\u201a \u00ce\u00b1\u00ce\u00b3\u00ce\u00bf\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00ac\u00cf\u201a. \u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b1 X\u00ce\u00b1\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00b1\u00ce\u00ba\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b7\u00cf\u0081\u00ce\u00b9\u00cf\u0192\u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b9\u00ce\u00ba\u00ce\u00ac \u00cf\u201e\u00ce\u00b7\u00cf\u201a \u00ce","lat":"40.634609","lng":"22.941081","walkId":"92"}

Comment: Are you sure it is getting inside the loop?

Comment: Does `$b` actually contain any data?

Comment: why make it hard for yourself, just use `$a[] = $row;`

Comment: Even if this worked, you'd only get the last value returned by fetch_assoc() because you're overwriting values all the time. Why not just push $row into $a ??

Comment: sgt BOSE the above is copy paste of my script, dotty the $b contains data (as I said with echo I am getting the data one by one) and Ghost I tried your solution by the same again.

Comment: this code works... it may come from somewhere else ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dd04a1f48a919a9727451efa8fb54162c44eb2f

Comment: no it doesn't from somewhere else. I have the same code in order to take the data from another table and for that it's work perfect but in this i am getting an empty array.

Comment: As I said it is copy paste from my script and with echo inside the while loop I am getting the data one by one but the array a is empty.

Comment: I tried the try-catch but it doesn't show anything. Also I used the ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
but it doesn't show anything too.

Comment: Can you check the number of rows that you are getting from the db?

Comment: @PrerakSola The problem is that he prints the content of $b, which is correct, so we're sure $a should be filled with it (and not empty)...

Comment: The code is working fine. I tested it on my side. There must be something else, else where that you are getting wrong.

Comment: Check with the column names for typing mistakes or you can try recreating that table.

Comment: Using the echo print_r($a,true); I am getting the data (finally) but in different version from that which returns the json_encode. In table I have greek characters but I have set the utf 8 and also in another table with greek I am getting the data correctly.

Comment: First thing I note is the special `?` that appears 3 time, the problem must come from here. Try to edit the 3 descriptions that contain the special `?` so it doesn't appear again in the print_r. Isn't it a greek char that cannot be read ? If it doesn't resolve the problem, please post the text, instead of images, so it is easier for me to manipulate.

Comment: Yes you are right Random. The problem was the special question mark. Now all data appears. But now the problem is with json_encode. When I am getting the data via http calls in my android app the greek characters are appeared strange. Any suggestion? Thanks for your help and for your time.

Comment: Cheers ! For your second question, I think you should make a new topic, because it is something really different, and I'm not sure I can help. I'll post the answer of the first question here for people who get the same problem. You should also remove comments that didn't help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I note is the special `?` that appears 3 time. The problem must come from here.
Try to edit the 3 descriptions that contain the special `?` so it doesn't appear again in the print_r.
That must turn `array_push` into an error.
You could also try to encode it in latin to make it safe. (please follow @deceze link to understand what to do)

Comment: `utf8_encode` converts from Latin-1 to UTF-8. The characters shown in the screenshot are clearly not Latin-1 encodable characters, so `utf8_encode` won't do any good here.

Comment: @deceze What should be used in this case so ? ( I'm french, so I always use utf8 to solve problems :) )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze I don't believe this is a duplicated, since the main question is about array_push problem... There were unexpected characters in the DB... The duplicate is for the 2nd question, which is actually about encoding...

Comment: There is no actual problem with `array_push` here, it's all just a problem with encodings.

Comment: When I posted the question I couldn't imagine that the problem was the encoding. The problem has been solved with @random's help. About the problem with encoding of greek characters I solved it with below code: $data[] = $row;
  $json = html_entity_decode(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
  echo $json;